# Profiling Mongo in client side

Tags: java, mongodb, profiling

I am very new at `Mongo` and I am trying to profile Mongo queries on the *application (mongo client) side*. I have a java application, which uses `mongodb` driver to query a Mongo database and I would like to log all queries and the time each query takes. Is it possible ?

Comment: Yes, using the [profiler](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/)   : `db.setProfilingLevel(2)`

Comment: db.setProfilingLevel( ) logs server side. The question is about client side logging...

Answer (score 2):

[JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) has a MongoDB probe. It can show you hot spots with backtraces, telemetries and single events.

[image]

Disclaimer: My company develops JProfiler

Answer (score 1):

You can configure MongoDB driver logging using regular Java logging backend:

[Configure logging for the MongoDB Java driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545341/configure-logging-for-the-mongodb-java-driver)

By default Mongo server will log all slow queries, i.e. those that take more than 100ms to execute. You can change that setting on the server.