# Mongodb replica set attaching "/" with Spring Data Framework

Tags: linux, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

My resplica set configuration is something like this:

```js
rs.glu:SECONDARY> rs.status()
{
    "set" : "rs.glu",
    "date" : ISODate("2014-04-03T04:34:35Z"),
    "myState" : 2,
    "syncingTo" : "10.13.96.13:27017",
    "members" : [
            {
                    "_id" : 2,
                    "name" : "10.13.98.14:27017",
                    "health" : 1,
                    "state" : 1,
                    "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                    "uptime" : 51453,
                    "optime" : Timestamp(1396448528, 1),
                    "optimeDate" : ISODate("2014-04-02T14:22:08Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2014-04-03T04:34:33Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2014-04-03T04:34:33Z"),
                    "pingMs" : 1
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 3,
                    "name" : "10.13.98.13:27017",
                    "health" : 1,
                    "state" : 7,
                    "stateStr" : "ARBITER",
                    "uptime" : 51453,
                    "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2014-04-03T04:34:33Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2014-04-03T04:34:33Z"),
                    "pingMs" : 1
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 4,
                    "name" : "10.13.96.13:27017",
                    "health" : 1,
                    "state" : 2,
                    "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                    "uptime" : 51453,
                    "optime" : Timestamp(1396448528, 1),
                    "optimeDate" : ISODate("2014-04-02T14:22:08Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2014-04-03T04:34:34Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2014-04-03T04:34:34Z"),
                    "pingMs" : 0,
                    "syncingTo" : "10.13.98.14:27017"
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 5,
                    "name" : "10.13.96.12:27017",
                    "health" : 1,
                    "state" : 2,
                    "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                    "uptime" : 51533,
                    "optime" : Timestamp(1396448528, 1),
                    "optimeDate" : ISODate("2014-04-02T14:22:08Z"),
                    "self" : true
            }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Now my connector code is this:

```js
List<ServerAddress> listOfServers = new ArrayList<ServerAddress>();
listOfServers.add(new ServerAddress(properties.getProperty("mongo.host1"), Integer.valueOf(properties.getProperty("mongo.port1"))));
listOfServers.add(new ServerAddress(properties.getProperty("mongo.host2"), Integer.valueOf(properties.getProperty("mongo.port2"))));
listOfServers.add(new ServerAddress(properties.getProperty("mongo.host3"), Integer.valueOf(properties.getProperty("mongo.port3"))));
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(listOfServers);
mongoClient.setWriteConcern(WriteConcern.ACKNOWLEDGED);

MongoDbFactory gameDbFactory = new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongoClient, properties.getProperty("adminportal.db"));
```

MongoTemplate gameMongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(gameDbFactory);

Here is my properties file:

```js
mongo.host1=10.13.96.12 
mongo.port1=27017

mongo.host2=10.13.96.13
mongo.port2=27017

mongo.host3=10.13.98.14
mongo.port3=27017
```

But when I try to connect my code I get this exception,

```js
WARNING: Server seen down: /10.13.96.12:27017 - java.io.IOException - message: Read  timed out
Apr 03, 2014 12:36:26 AM com.mongodb.ConnectionStatus$UpdatableNode update
WARNING: Server seen down: /10.13.96.13:27017 - java.io.IOException - message: Read timed out
Apr 03, 2014 12:36:46 AM com.mongodb.ConnectionStatus$UpdatableNode update 
WARNING: Server seen down: /10.13.98.14:27017 - java.io.IOException - message: Read timed out
Apr 03, 2014 12:38:14 AM com.mongodb.ConnectionStatus$UpdatableNode update
```

1. why this is happening, why there is a slash before the ip?
2. there is no where I attached the "/" in my code?

Am I thinking correct that this is the cause of the issue?

Thanks
Ankur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems an issue with the logger configuration and not an error.

Please refer to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/eAV7erPoZGU and [Configure logging for the MongoDB Java driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545341/configure-logging-for-the-mongodb-java-driver) for logger configuration for mongoDB.