# how to prevent logging on console when connected to mongodb from java?

Tags: java, mongodb, logging, mongo-java

I followed this [mongodb documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-java-driver/). Here is my code

```
public class JMongoDBCDemo
{
    MongoClient mongoClient;
    DB db;
    DBCollection coll;
    public JMongoDBCDemo()
    {
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
        db = mongoClient.getDB( "messenger" );
        coll = db.getCollection("users");
        DBObject myDoc = coll.findOne();
        System.out.println(myDoc);
        mongoClient.close();
        System.out.println("Got a collection...");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
            JMongoDBCDemo mongoDemo = new JMongoDBCDemo();
    }
}
```

Below is the output

```
Apr 05, 2015 12:17:47 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
Apr 05, 2015 12:17:47 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: No server chosen by ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary} from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=UNKNOWN, connectionMode=SINGLE, all=[ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
Apr 05, 2015 12:17:47 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:3}] to localhost:27017
Apr 05, 2015 12:17:47 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[2, 6, 1]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=2, maxDocumentSize=16777216, roundTripTimeNanos=389140}
Apr 05, 2015 12:17:47 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:4}] to localhost:27017
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "55201cec68fb70b6affba026"} , "name" : "prasad" , "password" : "123456"} //This is my output
Apr 05, 2015 12:17:47 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:4}] to localhost:27017 because the pool has been closed.
Got a collection... //my output
```

according to [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-java-driver/#finding-the-first-document-in-a-collection-using-findone) it should print like

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "55201cec68fb70b6affba026"} , "name" : "prasad" , "password" : "123456"}
Got a collection...
```

So can any one please help me to prevent these logs in console.

Comment: This might be helpful to you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545341/configure-logging-for-the-mongodb-java-driver

Comment: This doc link may be helpful to you: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver/reference/management/logging/

Comment: Any idea why there is "Opened connection .." more than once in log ? For me there are 3 entries whenever i try to connect . Please help .

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Thanks to [@jyemin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/986903/jyemin)
By using [MongoDB official documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver/reference/management/logging/) link

```
Logger mongoLogger = Logger.getLogger( "org.mongodb.driver" );
mongoLogger.setLevel(Level.SEVERE);
```

Now no logs are there in the console.

Comment: It would be better to configure this wherever main logging is configured, and SEVERE is almost certainly too restrictive.

Comment: Which `Logger`?  Like what package?

Answer (score 3):

You could just use

```
logging.level.org.mongodb.driver: ERROR
```

Answer (score 2):

import your Mongo client through "com.mongodb.**client**.MongoClient"

```
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;

import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Quick
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Logger.getLogger("org.mongodb.driver").setLevel(Level.WARNING);
        try (MongoClient mongo = MongoClients.create())
        {
            mongo.listDatabaseNames().forEach((Consumer<String>) System.out::println);
        }
    }
}
```

make sure you have the latest version of the driver, **3.12.2** at the time I wrote this answer

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.2</version>
</dependency>
```

---

if the above doesn't work, you're probably using a different logging module, look up how to turn that off, for example if you're using **slf4j**, create a file named "**simpleLogger.properties**" inside your resources folder and add this line to it

```
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel = warn
```

Answer (score 1):

i tried this `java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.mongodb.driver").setLevel(Level.OFF);`

it not worked, it still logs `com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log`

I changed it to JULLogger and it worked

`java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("JULLogger").setLevel(Level.OFF);`