# How to disable mongoDB java driver logging?

Tags: java, mongodb, logging

I am trying to disable log outputs of `mongo-java-driver-3.0.0`.

I have tried to set those in the beginning of my application, before loading the `mongo` drivers, but it didn't help.

```java
// Enable MongoDB logging in general
System.setProperty("DEBUG.MONGO", "false");

// Enable DB operation tracing
System.setProperty("DB.TRACE", "false");
```

I am getting this kind of logs:

```
11:01:15.406 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.protocol.query - Sending query of namespace susudev.Players on connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:28}] to server localhost:27017
11:01:15.406 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.protocol.query - Query completed

11:01:25.174 [cluster-ClusterId{value='554dbecb1b554f11e86c3a69', description='null'}-localhost:27017] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Checking status of localhost:27017
11:01:25.177 [cluster-ClusterId{value='554dbecb1b554f11e86c3a69', description='null'}-localhost:27017] DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Updating cluster description to  {type=STANDALONE, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE, roundTripTime=0.6 ms, state=CONNECTED}]
```

So my console is completely packed with mongo logs and I cant read anything.

Comment: How did you solve this annoying issue?? @Candroid

Comment: @jipr311 added a new answer

Comment: Does anybody know, what this output actually means? Maybe you can also configure the cluster and connection checking?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So this solved this issue:

```
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Level;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger;

...

static Logger root = (Logger) LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);

static {
    root.setLevel(Level.INFO);
}
```

You may set the `Level` to a higher `Level` if you wish to hide all the logs.

Comment: I don't get it, is that a log4j over slf4j? where is the **ch.qos.logback.classic.Level;** coming from??

Comment: logback library and slf4j

Answer (score 33):

To make this portion of code working you need to have **Logback**. 
(If maven project)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Then if you only want to disable Mongo driver logging, you should do something like this:

```
LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
Logger rootLogger = loggerContext.getLogger("org.mongodb.driver");
rootLogger.setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

Again to be clear, here is the list of import for this code to work:

```
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Level;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
```

This solution is for mongo java driver 3.0.0 and ^.

Edit: Here is a one liner with level set to ERROR.

```
((LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory()).getLogger("org.mongodb.driver").setLevel(Level.ERROR);
```

Comment: Men you saved my day. I tried everything and this is the only solution which worked

Comment: @arunkumarsambu Deleting `implementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-simple', version: '1.8.0-beta2'` from `build.gradle` helps for me.

Comment: I think the magic here is `.getLogger("org.mongodb.driver")`.  This does not seem to be documented anywhere.  Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 8):

If you need dynamic approach you can iterate over loggers and set level of them. Or you can set levels manually. Here are mongo driver loggers:

```
LogManager.getLogger("org.mongodb.driver.connection").setLevel(org.apache.log4j.Level.OFF);
LogManager.getLogger("org.mongodb.driver.management").setLevel(org.apache.log4j.Level.OFF);
LogManager.getLogger("org.mongodb.driver.cluster").setLevel(org.apache.log4j.Level.OFF);
LogManager.getLogger("org.mongodb.driver.protocol.insert").setLevel(org.apache.log4j.Level.OFF);
LogManager.getLogger("org.mongodb.driver.protocol.query").setLevel(org.apache.log4j.Level.OFF);
LogManager.getLogger("org.mongodb.driver.protocol.update").setLevel(org.apache.log4j.Level.OFF);
```

Comment: am using log4j and I did it by setting log4j property: props.setProperty("log4j.logger.org.mongodb.driver", "WARN");

Answer (score 6):

I've solved it using ,

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.Level;

Logger mongoLogger = Logger.getLogger( "org.mongodb.driver" );
mongoLogger.setLevel(Level.SEVERE); // e.g. or Log.WARNING, etc.
```

Comment: Worked for me -- driver 3.8.1

Answer (score 6):

in case you use xml resource to configure Logback you can easily do it by adding this:

`<logger name="org.mongodb.driver.cluster" level="OFF" />`

to your configuration.

Answer (score 3):

To disabled the **debug** logging into spring boot application of Mongo Driver, set the below configuration in the `logback-spring.xml` as below:

```
<logger name="org.mongodb" level="WARN" />
```

This will disable the logging into console logger as well as other loggers defined in the configuration file `logback-spring.xml`

Answer (score 2):

use the below import

```java
import java.util.logging.Logger;
```

use the below in code.

```java
Logger mongoLogger = Logger.getLogger( "com.mongodb" );
mongoLogger.setLevel(Level.SEVERE);
```

Answer (score 2):

For thoses who still face the problem with the logging, you have to set the log level of **org.mongodb.driver** to something higher like WARN or ERROR. The class com.mongodb is not used anymore even if it is still written in the logs.

See the last answer of this post: [Configure logging for the MongoDB Java driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545341/configure-logging-for-the-mongodb-java-driver)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, `MongoDB driver 3.5.0`, `SLF4j+Log4j12`, it's been sufficient adding:

```
log4j.logger.org.mongodb.driver=OFF
```

in my Log4j `.properties` configuration file.

Answer (score 1):

With Spring Boot, in `application.yaml` (you can also set it to `OFF`):

```yaml
logging:
  level:
    org:
      mongodb:
        driver: WARN
```

Answer (score 0):

import your Mongo client through "com.mongodb.**client**.MongoClient"

```
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;

import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Quick
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Logger.getLogger("org.mongodb.driver").setLevel(Level.WARNING);
        try (MongoClient mongo = MongoClients.create())
        {
            mongo.listDatabaseNames().forEach((Consumer<String>) System.out::println);
        }
    }
}
```

make sure you have the latest version of the driver, **3.12.2** at the time I wrote this answer

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.2</version>
</dependency>
```

---

if the above doesn't work, you're probably using a different logging module, look up how to turn that off, for example if you're using **slf4j**, create a file named "**simpleLogger.properties**" inside your resources folder and add this line to it

```
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel = warn
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use logback.xml for that purpose.
For example, my file

```
<configuration>
    <logger name="org.mongodb.driver.cluster" level="INFO"/>
    <logger name="org.mongodb.driver.protocol" level="INFO"/>
    <logger name="org.mongodb.driver.connection" level="INFO"/>
    <logger name="org.mongodb.driver.operation" level="INFO"/>
</configuration>
```

Put it into the `resources` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Using **slf4j** with **simplelogger.properties** file, I just added this line and it worked:

```
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.mongodb.driver=error
```

General log level stays in another line:

```
org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=info
```

Answer (score 0):

I use MongoDB Kotlin Driver in Ktor server and the easiest way to disable those logs (in case of the JVM server)

The Kotlin driver is new and it depends on the Java driver

you will need to go to the resources/logback.xml

and add this `<logger name="org.mongodb.driver" level="ERROR"/>` to the end before `</configuration>` so it will be something like this:

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="trace">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>
    <logger name="org.eclipse.jetty" level="INFO"/>
    <logger name="io.netty" level="INFO"/>
    <logger name="org.mongodb.driver" level="ERROR"/>
</configuration>
```