# Is there a way to configure log levels for MongoDB's open connection messages using logback?

Tags: java, mongodb, logging

I have changed configuration of mongodb driver to DEBUG, but it doesn’t help. I have tried other options of setting logs too, but it all seems not to work properly.

```
logging:
  level:
    root: info
    org.mongodb.driver.connection: debug
```

I am getting info logs like this constantly on INFO level:
`[LOGGG] INFO [MaintenanceTimer-1-thread-1][AnonymousUser] [] org.mongodb.driver.connection: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:12, serverValue:1403}] to localhost:27017`

But with closing connection the logging level is fine:
`2023-05-19 15:21:07,317 [LOGGG] DEBUG [SpringApplicationShutdownHook][AnonymousUser] [] org.mongodb.driver.connection: Closing connection connectionId{localValue:10, serverValue:1673}`

I am using `logback` system for logging.

Can someone tell what is the valid way of changing log level of opening connection as for now?

Comment: You cannot change the log level in a third-party lib code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me; it removes the excessive logging that MongoDB prints: [How to disable mongoDB java driver logging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30137564/how-to-disable-mongodb-java-driver-logging)