# Spring Data Mongodb: How to Dump Raw Query/Commands generated through QueryDsl?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, querydsl

I'm using [Spring Data's Querydsl integration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/querydsl/QueryDslPredicateExecutor.html) to execute my queries using predicates.

```
findAll(predicate, pageable)
```

Is there a way to dump the actual raw queries/commands that get executed?

I have also looked at the answer to this question and it wasn't working for me..
[Configure logging for the MongoDB Java driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9545341/configure-logging-for-the-mongodb-java-driver)

--Update--
I've managed to get the logging working by adding logging.level.org.mongodb.driver=DEBUG
in application.properties (not log4j.properties)

But still, I can't see the raw query that's being performed:

2016-03-23 21:50:56 DEBUG query:56 - Query completed
2016-03-23 21:50:56 DEBUG query:56 - Sending query of namespace testdb.reservation on connection [connectionId{localValue:4, serverValue:42631}] to server ds046785.mongolab.com:39186

Comment: On the MongoDB side, you may use the [profiler](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/analyzing-mongodb-performance/#database-profiling) with a profiling level set to `2` to log all the queries and commands the instance receives.

Comment: Ultimately, mongo java driver is responsible for sending the queries, so you can still set the `org.mongodb` log level to `DEBUG` and see the issued queries

Comment: I've added this line in my log4j.properties: log4j.logger.org.mongodb.driver=DEBUG  but there's still nothing logged

Comment: You might want to include your logging config in general and do some testing that it is configured correctly to at least log other components. Ultimately this does **all** have to go through the driver as was mentioned, so logging there would be the most valid option. I suggest you have configuration issues that you should include in the question so they can be resolved.

Answer (score 5):

Enable the profiler by setting the profile value using the following command in the mongo shell:

```
db.setProfilingLevel(2)
```

output of the profiler can be viewed using this command:

```
db.system.profile.find( { millis : { $gt : 100 } } )
```

This command displays all operations longer than 100 milliseconds

Comment: I've run the command db.setProfilingLevel(2) and then I run my query against the db, but the db.system.profile.find ({millis:{$gt:0}}) wont return the query im looking for

Comment: Yeah, same here, best will be to clean profile and run 'db.system.profile.find()' alone. You can clean profile like this: 'db.setProfilingLevel(0); db.system.profile.drop(); db.setProfilingLevel(2);'